# mPDF - Ln() use for line breaks or not?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, line-breaks, mpdf

I am transfering a little project from FPDF to mPDF, in FPDF there used to be `Ln()` for line break, in mPDF it is too, but it is not documented anywhere and yet, it's code does not have deprecation comment.

Is `Ln()` so obvious for everybody that it doesn't  need docs or is there a preferred way how to manually (I know about the mPDF auto line-break fancy stuff) insert line break in mPDF?

*Please note I am not creating HTML-based PDF, but a mm-based "typography" one, so if there is a way how to avoid inserting HTML line break, I would be glad :)*

Answer (score 0):

`Ln()` is taken over from FPDF and is used internally in the code. As a method with a capital letter it can be considered public and safe to use externally even though it is (as of now) not documented.